# unmatched close brace/bracket in URL when running curl coomand in python script

Tags: python, curl, gerrit

I need to use curl in my python script. Please do not advise me urlib2 or request modules.
Everything is OK when I try to send message without spaces or "\n"
so `message = "Test"` works fine. 
The problem occures when string contains space or any other whitespace characters. 
so when `message = "Test B"` I will see following error:

```
curl: (3) unmatched close brace/bracket in URL position 2: B}
```

My curl command is:

```
COMMAND = "curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -n -X POST -d '{'message': 'Test B'}' https://gerrit.zzz.com/a/changes/<some digits>/review"
subprocess.run(COMMAND, shell=True)
```

I tried almost every possible " and ' combinations and nothing work.

Comment: `{'message': 'Test B'}` is not valid JSON. JSON uses " not ' to enclose strings.

Comment: Also, why are using `curl` instead of `urllib` or `requests`. If you are going to use subprocess, why use `shell=True`, which creates these shell quoting issues?

Comment: if I dont use shell=True I'm getting "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -n -X POST -d "{"message": "A B"}"   I ca't use urllib because it's not installed on machines I'm running this code and it will not be installed in the near future. I tried request but for some reason I'm getting "requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='gerrit.zzz.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url"

Comment: How can `urllib` not be installed? It's part of core python and comes with every python installation. Check the docs again on how to use subprocess without shell=True.